# getline(); error using C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

When I try to run the following program, I get the following error from the `getline()` call.

**The message is:**

```
In function 'int main()':
error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'
```

I don't know why I got this - I have the `string` library included.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int NumeroLetras;

    cout << "Juego de El Ahorcado\n--------------------\n" << endl;

    cout << "N\243mero de letras de la palabra: ";
    cin >> NumeroLetras;

/*                Creamos el fichero con las palabras a adivinar
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    cout << "Creando fichero con palabras..." << endl;
    ofstream fichero("palabras.txt");
    fichero << "baloncesto\n";
    fichero << "beisbol\n";
    fichero << "futbol\n";
    fichero << "golf\n";
    fichero << "rugby\n";
    fichero << "tenis\n";
    fichero << "boxeo\n";
    fichero << "sumo\n";
    fichero << "judo\n";
    fichero << "nascar\n";
    fichero << "atletismo\n";
    fichero << "caminata\n";
    fichero << "ciclismo\n";
    fichero << "esgrima\n";
    fichero << "natacion\n";
    fichero << "polo\n";
    fichero << "clavados\n";
    fichero << "remo\n";
    fichero << "vela\n";
    fichero << "ajedrez\n";
    fichero.close();
    cout << "Fichero creado exitosamente..." << endl;

/*                Determinamos el tamaño de las palabras
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    string Palabra;

    fichero.open("palabras.txt");

    while (! fichero.eof())
    {
        getline(fichero, Palabra);

        cout << Palabra << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get that error?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't tag a C++ only question as "C". I will remove the gag for you.

Comment: ups, i'm sorry men, i didn't notice it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to read from an `ofstream` (**output** file stream)

Create a new `ifstream` variable and read from it.

Comment: Thanks men but let me ask you one more thing.
I did the change and i got another error with "ifstream fichero("palabras.txt");". Why?.

Comment: @RobertGomez _"... but let me ask you one more thing."_ Nope, one question per question please! Otherwise it doesn't fit for the desired format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Create a new question and you will get an answer.

Comment: @RobertGomez You should create a separate `std::ofstream` for output, the same way input operators didn't work on an output stream, output operators don't work on an input stream.